# Can mmap pass the address though a function?

Tags: c, ubuntu, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to use mmap to read physical memory on the beaglebone black. This normally works but I want to create a function because this code is repeated frequently. In this example I call the function memory. I just want to know if the function memory will return the address and will still be accessible once it's passed to back to main.

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    int read32bytes;
    volatile void *data;
    fd=open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
    *data=memory(fd, 64, 0);
    read32bytes=*data;
    munmap(data, 64);
    close(fd);
 }

volatile void *memory(int fd, int sizeInBytes, int offset)
{
    volatile void *address;
    address=mmap(0, sizeInBytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
    return address;
}
```

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in you code, as you dereference an uninitialized pointer when you call your function. And since it's a `void*` it won't even builds as you can't dereference a `void*` without casting. *And* you haven't declared the `memory` function before calling it, so the compiler will probably guess wrong what the function signature is. Other than that, there's no problem returning the pointer from a function, it's all in the same process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

And the only thing that I can see that you've done wrong is you've used `*data=` to assign the result to `data`. `*data = something` does *not* assign the variable `data`, but rather assigns the thing `data` points to (i.e. `*data`). Since `data` was never set to point to anything in particular, you don't know what you're assigning to, which is bad.

To assign the variable `data` to the result of calling the function, you'd use `data = memory(fd, 64, 0)` - just the same as if `data` was an `int` or any other type.

Comment: Whoops. Typed the example code to quickly... Thank you.